# Plotting and calculating the maximum value of a range of data in python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have a text file containing the data like this,

```
0  0  6
1  1  5
2  4  4
4  16 2
6  25 3
9  16 1
10 45 4
15 18 3
```

1st column (say x) is the independent variable and 2nd (y1) and 3rd (y2) columns are dependent variables.
Q1: How can I plot a graph (x,y1) and (x,y2) for a range of x value from 2 to 9?
Q2: How to get the maximum values of corresponding y1 and y2 within that range of x value (ie. x= 2 to 9 )?

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you mean, you can plot multiple lines in the same plot like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 15]
y1 = [0, 1, 4, 16, 25, 16, 45, 18]
y2 = [6, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3]

plt.xlim([2, 9])

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)

plt.show()
```

Also, to get the highest point:

```py
import numpy as np

x = [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 15]
y1 = [0, 1, 4, 16, 25, 16, 45, 18]
y2 = [6, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3]


y1 = [y1[i] for i in range(len(x)) if 2 <= x[i] <= 9]
y2 = [y2[i] for i in range(len(x)) if 2 <= x[i] <= 9]
x = [i for i in x if 2 <= i < 9]

print("y1 max:", np.amax(y1))
print("y2 max:", np.amax(y2))
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. However, how can I get the max value of y1 within that x range? I tried, y1_max=np.max(y1) but that considers all y1 values.

Comment: Sorry for not adding that immediately. I have added code to do that now.

Comment: @user19077881, I think that Kish wants the highest value from the **x** value of 2 to 9.

Comment: Your y1 max value of 9 does not make any sense to me. It what way is that a maximum related to y1?

Comment: My be my second question did not express what I mean. I have edited the question.
I want to get the max value of the corresponding y1 and y2 values associated with x (2 to 9).
The answer should be: y1 max: 25 and y2 max: 4

Comment: Does it also work for fractional values in the horizontal axis? I mean if X has both integer and float values. @sbottingota

Comment: I tested it and it does work. The condition works the same, and `matplotlib` can also be used with fractional amounts.